# Correct the Code c++ pointers and deletion

Tags: c++

I'm working through some problems for a C++ class I'm taking but I'm stuck on something that seems quite elementary.

Here is the question:

> Correct the code --
>
> ```
> string * p, *q;
> q = new string;
> p = q;
> delete p;
> delete q;
> ```

I entered this code into my IDE and it seemed to compile and run okay with the exception of a malloc error when deleting both `p` and `q`.  I changed it to just deleting `q`, and everything ran fine.  Is that the only error or am I missing something?

Comment: This fragment exhibits undefined behavior, by way of accessing an invalid pointer to already-deallocated storage. It calls `delete` on the same pointer twice.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik More accurately, it is calling `delete` on the same memory address twice, not on the same pointer twice.

Comment: The error is in using raw pointers in the first place. And likely in using pointers at all, when plain `string` plus the occasional reference or `std::move` is all you need 95% of the time.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Most probably it's for school/university and they usually learn raw pointers before using advanced C++ features...

Comment: @csabinho: I'm sure. And it's a valuable thing to learn. But anyone who is not learning CS from scratch should know this is the wrong way to write modern C++.

Comment: @ShadowRanger But that's how most universities and schools start C++, no matter if you think it's reasonable. That won't change the requirements.

Comment: @csabinho: Reread my last comment. I'm agreeing with you. My comment was more for the future benefit of said students when they actually try to use C++.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Students should learn languages in two ways simultaneously, one to pass the exam and one to use in real life after getting rid of the limitations and the "don't try this at home"-coding! ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`p` is set to point at the same `std::string` object in memory that `q` is pointing at.  Once you call `delete p`, the `string` object is destroyed and the memory block it occupied is reclaimed by your program's memory manager. Calling `delete q` afterwards to free the same object and memory a second time is **Undefined Behavior**, anything at all could happen, a crash is *not* guaranteed!  Only 1 `delete` is allowed for each successful `new`.

This is a job for a smart pointer (either [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) or [`std::shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)) to manage for you, you should not do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can and should only `delete` a pointer pointing to memory aquired by `new` once. `delete`ing it again is undefined behaviour and not `delete`ing it at all causes a memory leak.

So you answered the question correctly by changing it to `delete` only once.